# Use Spacy Models to find Modal Verb for languages fr, es, ru

Tags: nlp, spacy, linguistics

I am using Spacy models to find modal verb (MD) from following languages.

```
en
de
fr
es
ru
```

From `tag_map.py` of [en](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/tag_map.py) and [de](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/de/tag_map.py) it is clear that `"VerbType": "mod"` is a modal verb. But `tag_map.py` for [fr](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/fr/tag_map.py), [es](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/es/tag_map.py) and [ru](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/ru/tag_map.py) do not have any such property. How can I find out Modal verb in these 3 languages(on which properties should I focused on)? Also is there any generic way that I can find out the Modal verb of any language released by Spacy in the future let say greek is released?

Note: I am not looking for high-level tags but I am looking for low-level tags. In Spacy terminology, I am preferring `token.tag_` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a language-independent way to do so. But modal words are closed-classed words, so just checking if `token.tag_ == 'AUX'` (although in German, modal verbs are tagged as `VERB`) and if `token.lemma_` is in a set of modal verbs should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am working on a similar project.

For English, you can use `token.dep_ == 'AUX' and token.tag_ = 'MD'`.

for instance:

```
for token in doc:
    if token.dep_ == 'aux' and token.tag_ == 'MD': 
       print(token.text)
```

For German the closest I get is as like this:

```
sent = 'Ich muss auf den Lehrer hören'

nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
doc = nlp(sent)
print(doc.text)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_, token.morph)

Ich muss auf den Lehrer hören
Ich PRON sb Case=Nom|Number=Sing|Person=1|PronType=Prs
muss VERB ROOT Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=1|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin
auf ADP mo 
den DET nk Case=Acc|Definite=Def|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Art
Lehrer NOUN nk Case=Acc|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing
hören VERB oc VerbForm=Inf
    
for token in doc:
  if token.morph.get('VerbForm') == ['Fin']:
    print(token.text)

muss
```

You can also create a stoplist for German modals and add query to look in `token.lemma_`

```
modals = ['mussen']
for token in doc:
  if token.lemma_ in modals:
    print(token.text)

muss
```

I *am not sure about other languages* yet **stoplist** approach might work.

Comment: Question was about `French(fr), Spanish(es) and Russian (ru)` languages.